# Retrieve cookie from headers

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

On attempting to retrieve the cookie ID from a socket IO request, I have been using the handshake, header request.

```
socket.handshake.headers.cookie;
```

The output does return the cookie ID though it is attached to a string "cookieName".

```
cookieName=6941262055188417
```

To retrieve the number I was going to just use a string formatting tools to leave just the value after the

```
=
```

Is there a sleeker / more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Make sure you split on "&" too.

Comment: so splitting the string would be best?

Comment: I would split on "&" and then on "=" - remember, there may be more then one cookie. Perhaps someone else will have a different answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Multiple cookies are joined by `;` and a space, rather than by `&`.  So you'll need to split on the `; ` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = 'cookieName=12345';
string.split('=')[1]; // 12345
string.substring(11); // 12345
string.substring(string.indexOf('=') + 1); // 12345
```

But as said [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch), if you have more than one cookie, you can parse them using for example the native `querystring` module:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
querystring.parse(string, '&', '='); // {"cookieName": "12345"}
```

Comment: The example `querystring` given won't work for multiple cookies, as they are joined by `; ` rather than `&`.  So you can change parameters to split by `; `.